# How to detect a specific string text in a cell and remove it in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a list of locations in the format A2: [ **City State** ], where in the City or State can be made up of more than two words. All of this is in a single cell. I have the total data in thousands. Now, I also have a list of **State** with me. What I need to do is remove the State from A2 and just have the remaining string there. Thus leaving me with only **City**. I need help with this as the data is in millions and I have a list of around 30K cities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2 cells next to the cell that has the data one for City and one for State. enter the formulas and autofill down.

Formula to extract City

```
=left(A1,find(" ",A1,1)-1)
```

Formula to extract State

```
=right(A1,len(A1)-find(" ",A1,1))
```

These formulas take the text to the left of the first space and the text to the right of the first space.  You will have a problem if the city has a space e.g. "New York" but it is very difficult to work around that.

The other way to do this is to loop through all the cells using VBA code and run the same code on the cell and delete the State from that cell and place the State in a different cell.  it's a more complicated option.

**To solve the cities with 2 words problem**

I'm assuming that the Sates are US States and so I've created a string of all the US states that contain 2 words

[New Hampshire][New Jersey][New Mexico][New York][North Carolina][North Dakota][Rhode Island][South Carolina][South Dakota][West Virginia]

If you paste these states into cell B1 then you can use the formula below in cell B3 to check the contents of A3 and extract the city.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("[" & RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","☃",LEN(A3)-1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ",""))))) & "]",$B$1,1)),LEFT(A3,FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","☃",LEN(A3)-1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ",""))))-1),LEFT(A3,FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","☃",LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ",""))))-1))
```

Then paste the following formula into cell C3 to check the contents of A3 and extract the State.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("[" & RIGHT(F9,LEN(F9)-FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(F9," ","☃",LEN(F9)-1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F9," ",""))))) & "]",$B$1,1)),RIGHT(F9,LEN(F9)-FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(F9," ","☃",LEN(F9)-1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F9," ",""))))),RIGHT(F9,LEN(F9)-FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(F9," ","☃",LEN(F9)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F9," ",""))))))
```

**Formulas to deal with States with 3 words**

The formula is getting really long but all it's doing is checking for a match with a split at 3 spaces from the end and then 2 spaces and if a state is not found splitting at 1 space.

Extract City

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("["&RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","☃",LEN(A3)-2-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","")))))&"]",$B$1,1)),LEFT(A3,FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","☃",LEN(A3)-2-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ",""))))-1),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("["&RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","☃",LEN(A3)-1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","")))))&"]",$B$1,1)),LEFT(A3,FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","☃",LEN(A3)-1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ",""))))-1),LEFT(A3,FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","☃",LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ",""))))-1)))
```

Extract State

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("["&RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","☃",LEN(A3)-2-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","")))))&"]",$B$1,1)),RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","☃",LEN(A3)-2-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ",""))))),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("["&RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","☃",LEN(A3)-1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","")))))&"]",$B$1,1)),RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","☃",LEN(A3)-1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ",""))))),RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("☃",SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","☃",LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","")))))))
```

**How it works**
The formula looks for the second to last space by taking one away from the last space (thanks to user m4573r for the last space formula).  It then takes everything right of the last space, adds "[]" brackets and checks this against the State list text in B1.  If it exists then it uses the second last space at the point to cut the text in half and return either the City from the left or the State on the right.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. Like you said, I am facing problem with the the cities with spaces between them. And I have a lot of them. I was wondering if it could be done without using VBA. I am new to excel and still not familiar with a lot of formulas let alone VBA.

Comment: The only way to take those cities into account is to create your own list of citties that have 2 words so that the formula can check against them or a list of valid States may be easier.  Are they US States?

Comment: No , the data is of France. Hence the city names are of the likes "Ste Feyre La Montagne".

Comment: Although I do have the list of states with me in another sheet. I will the try the above formula. Will let you know if it works.

Comment: You only need to list the states that have a space and format them as I did with the US ones.  The problem is if any have more than one space.

Comment: Can the first formula that is pasted in B3 be edited in a way that it gives error message if it doesn't find anything from B1 instead of extracting string before space.

Comment: Yeah, if more than one space, its a problem I am also getting #VALUE error in the second formula that was to be pasted in C3.

Comment: Also, what is this ☃.

Comment: I'll test the formula again and add something to catch errors. The special character is used to find the last space. It's a clever formula that counts the spaces and then replaces the last space with the special character without knowing the position of that character so it then uses find to find the position of the spacial character. The guy who created the formula use the nose obscure character he could find.

Comment: I've checked the formula and I only get a #VALUE! errror if the value in column A only contins 1 word.  I've added the formulas to check for states that have 3 words.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon. I could get the job done. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad you got there in the end.  Must have saved a lot of time as I don't think a manual copy and paste on 30K records would be much fun.  If you click on the tick to accept my answer, that's all the thanks I need.